# error: package com.google.android.gms.games does not exist

Tags: java, android, libgdx

My imports are :

```
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;

import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;
```

I get this error in Android Studio

```
error: package com.google.android.gms.games does not exist
error: package com.google.example.games.basegameutils does not exist
Error:(87, 75) error: package GameHelper does not exist
Error:(116, 13) error: cannot find symbol class GameHelper
Error:(122, 28) error: cannot find symbol class GameHelper
Error:(230, 14) error: package Games does not exist
Error:(235, 14) error: package Games does not exist
Error:(242, 41) error: package Games does not exist
Error:(252, 41) error: package Games does not exist
Error:(259, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(263, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>Error:Execution failed for task ':android:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I have the `BaseGameUtil` imported as a module, and trying to integrate GPSS

I am also using Libgdx and updated the gradle to

```
include 'desktop', 'android', 'ios', 'core', 'BaseGameUtil'
```

So any ideas on what I did wrong?

Comment: You should accept the answer if it solved your problem, or comment on it if otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You must import google-play-services_lib as a library of your project.
You can find this at the following path:

```
<your-android-sdk-directory</extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
```

See [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) guide